# Why didn't Briar Cudgeon disappear from the Time Stop?

Tags: artemis-fowl

In Book 1, Artemis et al escaped from the time stop by drugging themselves to sleep.

In the same time stop, Julius Root "accidentally" plugged Briar Cudgeon with a tranquilizer dart.  Cudgeon fell asleep, but did not disappear from the time stop.  Why not?

Comment: Was Cudgeon actually *in* the time-stopped zone at the time, or did the fairies set up an FOB outside the zone?  I mean, they didn't go all the way back to Haven when they set off the bomb, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fowl Mastermind here.

The answer is simple biology. Artemis, Juliet and Butler are all humans [known as 'mud men' to the People]. Whereas the good Lieutenant Cudgeon was an elf. We can simply theorize that none of the People can escape a time stop, and that time stops only affect sleeping mud men-- especially since the magic was used in the past to deter mud men from intervening on fairy business [they hint about the elf and cobbler tale].

Another answer could be the fact that none of the People can leave a time stop until it ends due to their magic. Remember, though the generators for the time stop are technological, they are still using fairy magic.

TLDR; he didn't poof cuz he's a magic jerkwad.

Comment: OK, it's a good theory, and I'll go with that answer... though I reserve the right to change answer credit if anyone comes after you with a better theory.  :-)

Comment: Biology could be the answer, but not for the reasons cited in the answer: Cudgeon, Mulch and the troll move through the barrier of the time-stop seemingly unhindered.